# How to iterate over two lists and recycle the second one until the first one is over

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Basically I have these 2 lists

```py
listone = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']
listtwo = ['1', '2', '3']
```

And I want to iterate over both of the lists synchronously and whenever the shortest list ends (listtwo in this case) is restarts again until listone is finished.
Example:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 1
e 2
f 3
j 1
```

Like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

for i, j in zip(listone, cycle(listtwo)):
    print(i, j)
```

**output:**

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 1
e 2
f 3
j 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Without [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) or creating secondary list:

```py
listone = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']
listtwo = ['1', '2', '3']
N = len(listtwo)

for index, elem in enumerate(listone):
    elem2 = listtwo[index % N]
    print(elem, elem2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import ceil
listone = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'j']
listtwo = ['1', '2', '3']
listtwo_augmented = listtwo * ceil(len(listone)/len(listtwo))
for e1, e2 in zip(listone, listtwo_augmented):
    print(e1, e2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add-on to accepted answer,

In case of unknown list length.

```
from itertools import cycle

A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B = ["A","B","C"]

zip_list = list(zip(A, cycle(B)) if len(A) > len(B) else zip(cycle(A), B))

for i, j in zip_list :
    print(i, j)
```

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 A
5 B
6 C
7 A
8 B
9 C

[Program finished]
```